# Power BI M like VBA: execute M code from the button click and update the value of parameter?

Tags: powerbi

I have heard that Power BI has strong M language. How can I create button in PowerBI with an onClick handler which executes M code that update the value of tha parameter that is references in some other M code used by the query?